# focus() not working on native base floating label textInput in React native

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am not able to focus to next floating label `TextInput`.My code sample is here.I get error as `undefined is not a function(evaluating this.refs.LastName.focus())`.
Did anyone face this problem? please help me, thanks in advance.

```
<Item floatingLabel style={styles4.floatinglbl}>
<Label style={styles4.LblTxt}>First Name</Label>
<Input editable={true}
       value = {this.state.FirstName}
       returnKeyType={'next'}
       autoFocus={true}
       onChangeText={this.onFirstNameEditHandle}
       style={styles4.LblInpTxt}
       autoCapitalize={true}
       onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
         this.refs.LastName.focus();
       }}
/>
</Item>

<Item floatingLabel style={styles4.floatinglbl}>
    <Label style={styles4.LblTxt}>Last Name</Label>
    <Input editable={true}
     value={this.state.LastName}
     ref={'Lastname'}
     returnKeyType={'next'}
     onChangeText={this.onLastNameEditHandle}
     style={styles4.LblInpTxt}
     autoCapitalize={true}
    />
</Item>
```

Answer (score 4):

Holy hell this almost drove me up a wall. After 30 minutes *of trying to figure out how to move a cursor from one box to another* I finally sorted it out. If anyone has the misfortune of somehow being in the same position as I was (of wanting to move focus from one text input to another...), here's apparently a way to do it. I didn't see this in any of the documentation or anything and I think it's largely just a quirk of of how NativeBase operates. You can't reference `ref`. You have to reference `ref.wrappedInstance`. I'm assuming that their `Input` wraps `TextInput` for doing tricks like the floatingLabel.

```
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>Username</Label>
            <Input
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              spellCheck={false}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
              value={username}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
              returnKeyType="next"
              onSubmitEditing={() => { this.passwordInput.focus() }}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>Password</Label>
            <Input
              getRef={ref => {
                this.passwordInput = ref.wrappedInstance // <-- notice
              }}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              secureTextEntry={true}
              onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
              onSubmitEditing={() => { this.submit() }}
              value={password}
            />
          </Item>
        </Form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`refs` is being used by `this._textInput` and `this._root`.
Therefore you can use

```
this.refs.Lastname._root.focus()
```

Comment: I have used it,but still its not working..still getting undefined is not an object(evaluating this.refs.Lastname._root)

Comment: facebook has advised us to stop using refs

Answer (score 0):

Refer docs for FloatingLabel https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#floating-label-headref

It is mentioned in docs that,

> When using floatingLabel, use **getRef** to get the reference of 
>   component. Always wrap floatingLabel component in **`<Form/>`**.

Comment: can you share a sample example code of how to focus a floating label? I have tried the way you said but still facing the error undefined is not an object(evaluating this.getRef.Lastname)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
<Item floatingLabel>
  <Label>First Name</Label>
  <Input
    getRef={input => {
      this.firstNameRef = input;
    }}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
      this.lastNameRef._root.focus();
    }}
    returnKeyType={"next"}
  />
</Item>
```

And

```
<Item fixedLabel>
  <Label>First Name</Label>
  <Input
    ref={input => {
      this.lastNameRef = input;
    }}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
      this.lastNameRef._root.focus();
    }}
    returnKeyType={"next"}
  />
</Item>
```